# How to install -mysql -curl -gd -intl -pear -imagick -imap -mcrypt -memcache -ming -ps -pspell -recode -snmp -sqlite -tidy -xmlrpc -xsl on php7

Tags: server, mysql, php, php7

I am creating a website and on YouTube I saw someone paste this command in console to install additional extentions

```
apt-get install php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

I have php7 installed and this command is not working for me.

I need to install these PHP extensions: `-mysql -curl -gd -intl -pear -imagick -imap -mcrypt -memcache -ming -ps -pspell -recode -snmp -sqlite -tidy -xmlrpc -xsl`

To VPS Ubuntu, but with php7, for example:  php7-mysql

Comment: I recommend you **[edit]** this with a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do. Right now this is unclear.

Comment: First of all you should know which minor version of PHP 7.x you need. In my Ubuntu 16.04 there are 3 of them - **php7.0**, **php7.1**, **php7.2**.

Comment: Why are you using a video using php5 to configure a web server using php7 ? At a minimum it sounds as if your video is a bit long in the tooth and php packages may have changed in the last 2 releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search it by this command:

```
apt-cache search php7.0
```

After the search, you can install anything you need, for example:

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

If the first command isn't help, you need to run apt-get update as well.

Comment: Or use the web package search - https://packages.ubuntu.com/ yields https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7&searchon=names&suite=zesty&section=all .